# Phone 7: how does it execute code?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, mobile

Unfortunately, Google didn't help me much: I'm looking for some information regarding the execution of applications (written with the Phone 7 Developer Tools) on Windows Phone 7.

- is it normal .NET bytecode that is deployed to the Phone?
- If yes, is there some kind of JIT compiler on the phone?

In genereal, I'm interested in how Phone 7 executes programs and if there are differences to Android's or IOS' concept.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> is it normal .NET bytecode that is deployed to the Phone?

Yes.

> If yes, is there some kind of JIT compiler on the phone?

Yes, it's contained in the CLR. It's a mobile version of the desktop CLR that runs on the phone but it is exactly the same principle. The JITer translates the MSIL code into native code at runtime.

Android supports both native code and managed code. If you use Java managed code, there is a virtual machine and a bytecode process compilation happening at runtime.

Objective-C for the iPhone is different as it is already native code that doesn't require further compilation.

Comment: Wow, that was fast, thanks. So I assume Android does the same (some kind of Java bytecode + dalvik vm). The last thing I want to know is the comparison to IOS. I know it is Objective C on IOS, but does this code run directly on the IPhone or is there also some kind of Jitting in between?

Comment: @alapeno, no, Objective C doesn't use just-in-time compilation. There's no virtual machine. Here's an interesting article you may checkout: http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/07/is-virtual-machine-for-cocoa.html

Comment: Objective C produces native code, so it doesn't require any VM to run.  Android also supports native code.  Windows Phone 7, unfortunately, does not.

Comment: Android supports Native code as which can interacted through using JNI calls. Dalvik VM is basically an interpreter (currently Mterp) which interprets DEX code and not Java bytecode. JIT is an optional features which will kick in when if finds a hot trace which, believe it nor not, becomes hot only in 40 iterations (its hardcoded - u can change it if you wanna compile your own version). Dalvik also support hot method based JIT but is not as efficient.

Answer (score 4):

If you are familiar with how the code is executed on a Windows machine, Windows Phone is very similar.

iOS is actually different. It does not allow JIT compilation. For example MonoTouch is precompiling applications before running. See [Mono Touch Limitations](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/about/limitations)

Comment: Ok thanks, so this means the Code for IOS applications is compiled on the developers machine and runs "natively" on the Phone without any further mechanisms needed?

Comment: The 'default' way to develop for iOS is actually using Objective-C which is compiled to native code (as is typical for C/C++ languages).